# Video Plugin for Elgg 1.8

Tags: php

I am working on Elgg site of version 1.8 here i need to add a video plugin to my site in which 
 it  allow you to add a youtube URL using the plugin and playback the video with comment block at the bottom and  allow comments to be made in the page for the video without having the whole page refresh.but i am unable to get the plugin for 1.8 version for this i added izap-izap-video plugin but it is giving a comparability error saying

"Requires  Plugin: izap-elgg-bridge >= 2.1
 Requires  PHP extension: curl" can any one suggest me to fix the above issue or suggest me if their is any other plugin which supports for Elgg 1.8 version and satisfies the above requirement

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

For simple video plugin for 1.8 : http://community.elgg.org/pg/plugins/project/740863/developer/plugingalaxy/videos-plugin-for-elgg-18

For video upload plugin for Elgg 1.8 solution : http://www.webgalli.com/elgg_plugins/profile/2831/videos-plugin-for-elgg-18

Answer (score 1):

This is not any kind of error. It is a compatibility issue. Actually, the plugin requires one more addition to run on your `elgg` site. `iZAP elgg bridge`.

Download it: http://www.pluginlotto.com/store/product/tarun/15877/izap-elgg-bridge-free-elgg-plugin 
and install on your site.

The videos will move just fine. `izap-elgg-bridge` is an amazing thing to work with. keep exploring...